# Grouping XML Values Based On XML Attributes (XSLT)

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Below are three rows of data (tab separated) that are to be transformed into an XML using XSLT.

```
Column_1     Column_2     Column_3     Column_4
A            B            C            D
A            B            A            F
C            B            D            C
```

The Expected output is as below

```
<firstTag Column_1 ='A' Column_2='B'>
   <secondTag Column_3='C'  Column_4='D'/>
   <secondTag Column_3='A'  Column_4='F'/>
</firstTag>
<firstTag Column_1 ='C' Column_2='B'>
   <secondTag Column_3='D'  Column_4='C'/>
</firstTag>
```

How would one be able to group these rows based on one or more attribute values (Column_1 and Column_2) using XSLT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unparsed-text` or (in XSLT 3 supported since 2017 by Saxon 9.8 and later) `unparsed-text-lines` to process non-XML text files like the one you seem to have, then you have the `tokenize` function plus the `xsl:analyze-string` element or in XSLT 3 the `analyze-string` function to process and structure your tab delimited data into something you can feed to `xsl:for-each-group`, i.e.  some XML or some mixture of arrays and sequences of string in XSLT 3.

Grouping in XSLT 2 and 3 is covered in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info.

[Here is an example using XSLT 3](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%09xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%09xmlns%3Amath%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmath%22%0D%0A%09xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%0D%0A%09xmlns%3Aarray%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Farray%22%0D%0A%09exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%09version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22text%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%3EColumn_1%20%20%20%20%20Column_2%20%20%20%20%20Column_3%20%20%20%20%20Column_4%0D%0AA%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20D%0D%0AA%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20F%0D%0AC%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22el1%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%3EfirstElement%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22el2%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%3EsecondElement%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22rows%22%20as%3D%22array%28xs%3Astring%29*%22%20select%3D%22%28%24text%20%3D%3E%20tokenize%28%27%5Cr%3F%5Cn%27%29%29%20%21%20array%20%7B%20tokenize%28.%2C%20%27%5Cs%2B%27%29%20%7D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22data-rows%22%20select%3D%22%24rows%20%3D%3E%20tail%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22column-names%22%20select%3D%22%24rows%5B1%5D%3F*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cresult%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22%24data-rows%22%20composite%3D%22yes%22%20group-by%3D%22%3F1%2C%20%3F2%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aelement%20name%3D%22%7B%24el1%7D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aattribute%20name%3D%22%7B%24column-names%5B1%5D%7D%22%20select%3D%22current-grouping-key%28%29%5B1%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aattribute%20name%3D%22%7B%24column-names%5B2%5D%7D%22%20select%3D%22current-grouping-key%28%29%5B2%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aelement%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fresult%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%5B.%20instance%20of%20array%28xs%3Astring%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aelement%20name%3D%22%7B%24el2%7D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each%20select%3D%22%3F%283%20to%20array%3Asize%28current%28%29%29%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aattribute%20name%3D%22%7Bsubsequence%28%24column-names%2C%20position%28%29%20%2B%202%2C%201%29%7D%22%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aelement%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=&input-type=None) and `for-each-group` over a grouping population that is a sequence of arrays of strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="text" as="xs:string">Column_1     Column_2     Column_3     Column_4
A            B            C            D
A            B            A            F
C            B            D            C</xsl:param>


  <xsl:param name="el1" as="xs:string">firstElement</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="el2" as="xs:string">secondElement</xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="rows" as="array(xs:string)*" select="($text => tokenize('\r?\n')) ! array { tokenize(., '\s+') }"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="data-rows" select="$rows => tail()"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="column-names" select="$rows[1]?*"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$data-rows" composite="yes" group-by="?1, ?2">
            <xsl:element name="{$el1}">
                <xsl:attribute name="{$column-names[1]}" select="current-grouping-key()[1]"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="{$column-names[2]}" select="current-grouping-key()[2]"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(xs:string)]">
      <xsl:element name="{$el2}">
          <xsl:for-each select="?(3 to array:size(current()))">
              <xsl:attribute name="{subsequence($column-names, position() + 2, 1)}" select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I copied the input sample from your question it didn't seem to contain tab characters so I tokenized on whitespace instead.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same in XSLT 1.0? Please do ignore the spaces, they are actually tab seperated.

Comment: @Kitt, I wouldn't want to do it in XSLT 1 with the simple string functions it has and the lack of plain text parsing. There are some ways to fake the plain text into an XML document using external entities and some XSLT 1 processors have extensions to tokenize or split data. And in theory XSLT 1 is Turing complete so you can implement such stuff with named templates. But I don't consider XSLT 1 a good tool for that and would suggest to use XSLT 2  or later or to preprocess the plain text to XML with some other tool that has more powerful string processing than XSLT 1.

Comment: Appreciate the help @Martin. Will update to the latest version. Thank you.